# Is $\lambda_{\min}(A) \geq \lambda_{\min}(B)$ when $A > B$ where $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

Is $\lambda_{\min}(A) \geq \lambda_{\min}(B)$ when $A > B$ where $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite matrices? Here $A > B$ means $A-B$ is positive definite matrix.

Comment: Note that $\lambda_\min(B) = \min_{\|u\|=1} u^TBu$.

Comment: There exists $u$ such that $\|u\| = 1$ and
$\lambda_{\min}(A) = u^\top A u = u^\top B u + u^\top (A - B)u \ge \lambda_{\min}(B) + \lambda_{\min}(A - B)$.